# How do I disable the Java updater on OS X?

Tags: macos, java, bug, auto-update

I've disabled automatic checking for Java updates the Java Control Panel, but my changes are always ignored, as I can confirm by checking the control panel after making and saving my changes:

[image]

How do I *really* disable automatic checking for Java updates?

Comment: H ow do you start the Java control panel?

Comment: @Mark: From System Preferences.

Comment: Duplicate indeed; and what a bug!